# Google app engine exercise 2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was doing [this example](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise2.html) and I'm stuck at Ex2, item 2.Creating one to many relationship

It gives me error on the line of code:

```
logger.log(Info.WARNING, e.getMessage());
```

The error is this:

Multiple Markers at this line
-logger cannot be resolved
-info cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Logger and Level in order for this line to work.

```
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
```

The log method in logger accept a level and a string here. Change the line as follow ans everything will be  fine:

```
logger.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
```